# How can I test a dialog has been opened correctly with Angular and Jest

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test a dialog (Angular 12 + Jest) that is expected to be opened when user click a button, but my current implementation is offering me a false positive.

This is my test:

```
test('should open suppliers dialog', () => {
    const openDialogFunction = jest.spyOn(component, 'showSuppliersDialog')
    fixture.debugElement
      .query(By.css('.suppliers-dialog-button'))
      .triggerEventHandler('click', null)
    expect(openDialogFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
    dialogFixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      const suppliersDialogDOM = fixture.debugElement.query(
        By.css('.agency-suppliers-dialog')
      )
      expect(suppliersDialogDOM).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })
```

1. In `openDialogFunction` I'm spying on the function that triggers the dialog opening.
2. Then I'm emulating the click event on the actual button that manages the boolean variable that shows or hides the dialog.
3. After that I tried to assure that `openDialogFunction` function has been called properly.
4. Now we found the tricky area because with...

```
const suppliersDialogDOM = fixture.debugElement.query(
   By.css('.agency-suppliers-dialog')
)
expect(suppliersDialogDOM).toBeTruthy()
```

...I'm querying the css class name that DOM must contains in case the dialog has been properly opened, and finally I expect this reference to the dialog DOM to be truthy.

The point is I'm trying to wrapp this logic inside `whenStable()` function because inside the dialog component we have to wait until a `forkjoin` to be resolve before switching `dialogVisible` boolean to true and that way show the dialog. But I've checked that the test doesn't run inside this `whenStable()`, so this is offering a falsy positive. Otherwise, if I remove this `whenStable()` wrapper this test shows a truthy negative because at this time the `forkJoin` has not been resolved and the last expect sentence is false because the DOM doesn't contains the dialog yet.

```
loadData() {
    let observables = []
    observables.push(this.someService.getProviders())
    observables.push(this.anotherService.getOperator())
    forkJoin(observables)
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: Generic | unknown) => {
        // some logic here
        this.dialogVisible = true
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // some logic here
      })
  }
```

I'm noob with frontend testing and maybe my approach is not the ideal, or I'm making complex anything supposed to be more simple. So I would be very grateful if anyone help me. Thanks!

Comment: wrap your test callback in async zone https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync and then call https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flushMicrotasks

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Eggy, but unfortunately I've tried it within the code I previously provided and it doesn't work. After calling `dialogComponent.loadData()` and calling `flushMicrotask()`... `suppliersDialogDom` remains being null.

Comment: Is block that toggles visibility of a dialog runs at all?

Comment: Yes, the feature is working live with no problems.

Comment: I meant in test

Comment: Sorry, I don't understrand your question, but I can say the test never go inside `whenStable()` because I placed a console.log inside and never shows up.

Comment: Yep, so put a console.log just before `this.dialogVisible = true;`, see if executed in test.

Comment: Ok, if I put the console.log just before `this.dialogVisible = true` it never shows, however, if I put a console.log on the first line of the loadData function it does show but surprisingly three times. Does this mean that the test does not resolve the forkjoin... I am very lost

Comment: Well then, you must isolate this test case. mock services and so on. Karma also have a debugger you can use to set breakpoints in your test case and source code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to take another approach to test this feature, and instead of testing it from the parent component that contained the button that raised the dialog, now I test the dialog component itself as follows:

This is the function that opens the dialog:

```
getData(observables: unknown[]) {
    forkJoin(observables)
      .toPromise()
      .then((data: Generic | any) => {
        // some code
        this.dialogVisible = true
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // some message to show
      })
  }
```

And this is my test:

```
it('should open suppliers dialog', () => {
    const getDataFunction = jest
      .spyOn(component, 'getData')
      .mockImplementation(() => {
        component.dialogVisible = true
      })
    component.getData([])
    expect(getDataFunction).toHaveBeenCalled()
    const suppliersDialogDOM = screen.getByTestId('agency-suppliers-dialog')
    expect(component.dialogVisible).toBeTruthy()
    expect(suppliersDialogDOM).toBeVisible()
  })
```

That way I check if the boolean variable that make visible or not my dialog is truthy, and I also check if the element that I have queried through data-testid really exists in the DOM.

I'm not sure if making this `spyOn` and `mockImplementation` where I set the boolean value could be origin of false positives, I hope don't.

Thanks.